# Sharing storage among VMs

Tags: google-app-engine, azure, amazon-web-services

I have used aws, azure and google-aapengine but i find the ability to share a storage lacking in them(correct me if i am wrong). My basic need is to have multiple vm instances having a common storage. My setup is 
Having 2 sets of servers. 1st set will be running a web-app that will upload files. 2nd set will be processing the files. None of these services allow you to attach common disks to multiple vms. I tried to create [AzureFileService](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/12/introducing-microsoft-azure-file-service.aspx) But the 1st step is giving error. `Get-Account` does return me my account data.

```
$ctx=New-AzureStorageContext <account name> <account key>
```

I wrote got no clue what that `<account key>` is. I tried using the Azure login password as account-key but got the following error

```
PS C:\> $ctx=New-AzureStorageContext mewtoo **password**
New-AzureStorageContext : Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
At line:1 char:6
+ $ctx=New-AzureStorageContext mewtoo *********
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureStorageContext], FormatException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Common.Cmdlet.NewAzureStorageContext
```

Obviously the last option would be to upload/download the files using HTTP calls. But the files can be 100MB to 1GB+ in size so downloading each file processing them and uploading back will be time consuming. If better solutions are available, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account key is the access key for your storage account, which you can find in the management portal:

[image]

Here's a step-by-step guide to create a new share: http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/09/23/step-by-step-create-a-file-share-in-azure.aspx

Comment: That did work, thanks alot. But i have a little query, How do i connect it with the two vms?